# How to expose ssh to the internet?

Tags: networking, ssh

I run the search on google and ALL I can find is a bunch of nonsense about how dangerous it is to do this with only a password...followed with a link to the instructions on the ubuntu website for setting up a public key system.

Ok, I've got the public key figured out.   Now, how do I actually expose ssh to the internet?

I am running on a local network in the house and need to access my desktop from school...

Would NGROK help with this?

Comment: Your home router probably contains a firewall which has to be instructed about the ssh server. This is not a Ubuntu problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set up port forwarding on your router, and forward port 22 of router to port 22 of your machine. People connecting to the router ( piblic ip ) of your home network will be forwarded to your home computer. As this setting varies from router to router, i cannot provide an example. Refer to your routers user manual

Answer (score 0):

port forwarding from router is the best way to do this and the alternative way is to install remote softwares like [teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) if you are on ubunu desktop.

Comment: Ok, so this teamviewer thing is secure? And will have the same level of performance as an ssh with an exported display? Because I abandoned the remote desktop because ssh was so much faster...